# ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(6,43): error TS2307: Cannot find module './angular-signature-pad'

Tags: canvas, signature, angular6

i am trying to develop signature canvas and installed npm install angular-signature-pad --save, 
i am able to see the component under node_modules folder->angular-signature-pad->angular-signature-pad,

trying to import in app.module.ts

import { AngularSignaturePadModule } from 'angular-signature-pad/angular-signature-pad';

tried other way

import { AngularSignaturePadModule } from 'angular-signature-pad';

it throws ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular-signature-pad/angular-signature-pad' in 'F:\angular workspace\my-dream-app\src\app'

please let me know what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use angular2-signature-pad

```js
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { SignaturePadModule } from 'angular2-signature-pad';

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule,
    SignaturePadModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

code sample for reference - https://codesandbox.io/s/9ll0p7yoko